# Python way to convert argument list to string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've inherited some Python code that constructs a string from the string arguments passed into `__init__`:

```
self.full_tag = prefix + number + point + suffix
```

Maybe I'm just over-thinking it but is this the best way to concatenate the arguments? I know it's possible to do something like:

```
self.full_tag = "".join([prefix, number, point, suffix])
```

Or just using string format function:

```
self.full_tag = '{}{}{}{}'.format(prefix, number, point, suffix)
```

What is the Python way of doing this?

Comment: All of these ways are OK.  Generally, `+` is likely to be the least efficient (though you should `timeit` to be sure ;-).  If it's not a bottleneck though, I'm not sure that any of the ways really matter _too_ much.  They're all fairly clear in what you're trying to accomplish with that line of code...

Comment: Nice, I see recommendations for each option. So I guess it depends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation recommends `join` for better performance over `+`:

> [6. ... For performance sensitive code, it is preferable to use the str.join() method which assures consistent linear concatenation performance across versions and implementations.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#index-22)

If performance is not too important, it's more of a matter of taste.

Personally, I find `"".join` cleaner and more readable than all of those braces in the `format` version.

Answer (score 3):

*Pythonic* way is to follow [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), which has several things to say about this case:

- Beautiful is better than ugly.
- Simple is better than complex.
- Readability counts.

Add to that the famous quote by DonaldKnuth:

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time:
>   premature optimization is the root of all evil.

With those in mind, the best of your choices is:

```
self.full_tag = prefix + number + point + suffix
```

Although, if number is really a number and point point is really a point, then this is more explicit:

```
self.full_tag = "%s%d.%s" % (prefix, number, suffix)
```

- Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: "[`str.format`] is the new standard in Python 3, and should be preferred to the `%` formatting described in String Formatting Operations in new code."

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Comment: @Alden that is correct, `format` seems to be endorsed by the creators of Python, but I personally still prefer the old `printf` syntax. Perhaps I am just old-fashioned, but it looks simpler and more readable to me.

Comment: With @Alden's point in mind, this is a very nice answer. For sake of completeness, [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) is a full link to PEP20.

Comment: @mwormser Thanks, I included the link in the answer.